# Can someone help me to prove $P(A \cap B|A\cup B)\le P(A\cup B|A).$

Tags: probability-theory, bayes-theorem

What I have done is to say that $(A\cap B)\cap(A\cup B)=A\cap B$ and $(A\cap B)\cap A=(A\cap B).$ And, I cannot see if $P(A\cup B)\ge P(A)$ to use Baye's law  $\frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A\cup B)}\le \frac{P(A\cap B)}{P(A)}.$

Comment: You can read $P(A\cup B|A)$ as the probability that $A$ or $B$ occured given that $A$ occured. What is that probability?

Answer (score 2):

You can say

- $A \subset A\cup B$  so $\mathbb P(A\cup B) \ge P(A)$ but more importantly $\mathbb P(A\cup B \mid A) =1$
- $\mathbb P(A\cap B \mid A\cup B)$ is a conditional probability so cannot exceed $1$
- so $\mathbb P(A\cap B \mid A\cup B) \le \mathbb P(A\cup B \mid A)$

You may need $\mathbb P(A) > 0$ for $\mathbb P(A\cup B \mid A)$ to be well-defined; if it is then $\mathbb P(A\cup B) >0 $ so $\mathbb P(A\cap B \mid A\cup B)$ will also be well-defined.

Comment: what do you mean in the second bullet

Comment: @Pel All probabilities must be no smaller than $0$ and no greater then $1$.  If this is not immediately obvious, you can prove it from [Kolmogorov's probability axioms](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_axioms)

Comment: Thank  you!! At first i thaught that i could prove it with Baye's law but i stuck to show that P(A)<=P(AUB)

Comment: [Thomas Bayes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Bayes) so perhaps Bayes law or Bayes' law or Bayes's law rather than Baye's law